# jquery how to check if the scroll is almost down

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

There are a lot of websites (like www.9gag.com) that check your scroll percentage and identify if you are 80% down. If so, it displays more content.

Example of code that I would like to see:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if(scroll.height >= 80%) {
        // the scroll is about 80% down.
    }
});
```

I would like to know how I can check if the scroll is about 80% down, like those websites?

Comment: You wouldn't want to test for a percentage if you want to continuously expand the page. The part of the page that has not been seen when loading more content would become bigger and bigger. Instead use a constant.

Answer (score 7):

You check what is height of the page, and compare this value to current position. If current position is 80% of the heigh than you run some code.

```
$(window).scroll(function ()
{
    var content_height = $(document).height();
    var content_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var percentage_value = content_scroll_pos * 100 / content_height;

    if(percentage_value >= 80)
    {
        console.dir("the scroll is about 80% down.");
    }
});
```

Didn't test it, but should do what you want :)

thanks to Alvaro for adding my code to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wSSS/7/

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the window height in every scroll event. Not ideal because is gonna be the same :)

Comment: @Alvaro think better. he wants to create infinite scroll. so window height will change.

Comment: window height wont change though. window height is the height of the browser window not the content

Comment: It is not working well. The `content_height` is always more than the `content_scroll_pos`, which never reaches it. Take a look at the console: http://jsfiddle.net/2wSSS/7/

Comment: @Alvaro 2880 is 80% of 3544. So rest is irrelevant.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze Your message never gets printed in the console. It never enters in the condition.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze you are trying it with an thinner screen than mine. In my screen your `percentage_value` never reaches `80`  (the values Im getting are `2660 vs 2048 vs 76.99248120300751 ` being the last one the percentaje.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have to do:

```
//when scrolling...
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowsHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    //if I scroll more than 80%
    if( ((currentScroll *100) / windowsHeight) > 80){
         //do whatever
   }
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/2wSSS/6/

Comment: This does not take into account the document length at all.

Comment: @DGS what about the `$(window).height()`?

Comment: that is not related to the document length just the viewport height.

Comment: still doesnt work as intended since you havent included the windows height in the equation. It would currently require the top of the page to be below 80%

Comment: `windowsHeight` makes reference to the document height.

Comment: change `var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop()` to `var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();` and it will work as expected.

Comment: @DGS dis you check my fiddle? It is working as expected right now :)

Comment: Yeah and mine has been working as expected for a while now but still downvoted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37580/discussion-between-dgs-and-alvaro)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( window ).bind( 'scroll', function( event ) {
        var win = $( this ),
            doc = $( document ),
            winH = win.height(),
            winT = win.scrollTop(),
            docH = doc.height(),
            interval = parseInt( winH * 0.2, 10 );

        if( docH - winH - winT < interval ) {
            console.log( 'the scroll is about 80% down' );
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > 0.8 * $(document).height()) {
        $('body').append("<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div><div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>")
    }
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wSSS/10)

Has an example of dynamic content being added when page is scrolled below 80%

Comment: That's not 80%, but 80 pixels from the bottom.

Comment: It is working for me on chrome. When you scroll below 80% extra divs get added to the content. You should be able to infinitely scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

Since there hasn't been a chosen answer, here's what I use to detect how far from the bottom in pixels, rather than percentage:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 300) { });
```